# File doesn't get uploaded in folder php

Tags: php, post, file-upload

I need to upload a file in a folder but the file never get in the folder. The name of the file is added correctly but no file in the folder. What is going wrong?

Php error: Undefined index: foto on line 12-16

```
$name= $_FILES["foto"]["name"];
$type= $_FILES["foto"]["type"];
$size= $_FILES["foto"]["size"];
$temp= $_FILES["foto"]["temp_name"];
$error= $_FILES["foto"]["error"];

if ($error > 0)

   die("Error uploading file! code $error.");

   else
   {
       if($type=="image/png" || $size > 2000000)//condition for the file
   {

       die("Format  not allowed or file size too big!");
   }

   else   
   {
    move_uploaded_file($temp,"assets/");
    echo "Upload complete!"; 
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form id="form" style="margin-left: 200px"  action="addNewProduct.php"      method="post"><br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div id="imageUpload">
                <label for="foto">Foto</label>
                <input type="file" name="foto" /><br>
            </div>
            <div id="infoForm">
                <label for="productNaam">Productnaam</label>
                <input type="text" name="productNaam"/><br>
                <br>
                <label for="beschrijving">Productbeschrijving</label>
                <input type="text" name="productBeschrijving" /><br>
                <br>
                <label for="btw">BTW</label>
                <input type="number" name="productBtw" /><br>
                <br>
                <label for="prijsinclbtw">PrijsInclBTW</label>
                <input type="number" name="productPrijsInclBtw" /><br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>

                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add new Pen">
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: sounds like `$_FILES["foto"]` isn't actually a thing. Try `var_dump($_FILES)`

Comment: Show us form in HTML

Comment: I think your file destination needs to be "assets/" . $name

Comment: @BigScar: but the problem is many lines above :-)

Comment: @panther There might be more than one error here.

Comment: @BigScar html not correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you upload files, `form` has to have `enctype` attribute.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form" style="margin-left: 200px" action="addNewProduct.php" method="post">
      ^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `$_FILES["foto"]["temp_name"];` is incorrect, you should change it to `$_FILES["foto"]["tmp_name"];`

And your folder `assets` should exist in your root folder.

Your form should like this:

```
<form action="uploads.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="foto">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Please try this, hope this help you out : `uploads.php`

```
$type= $_FILES["foto"]["type"];
$size= $_FILES["foto"]["size"];
// $temp= $_FILES["foto"]["temp_name"];

$file_name = $_FILES["foto"]["name"];      
$source = $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'];
$dir = "./assets/";
$file = $dir . $file_name;
//$directory = "./assets/upload/$file_name";
if(!file_exists ($file ))
{
    move_uploaded_file($source,$file );
    exit();
}
else
{
    echo "File exist";
}
```